# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de columnas dinamicas en C# .net para realizar un listado?

Tags: c#, .net, pivot, epplus

Estoy haciendo un método Listar en C# .net y en el momento de obtener cada valor
dentro del objeto son demasiados campos de fecha y ademas de ello el nombre de la columnas son dinámicos así que cambian de acuerdo al mes.

Lo que quiero saber es como manejar los valores dinámicos en este caso las fechas.

```
public List<Sigeri> ExportarResumenHoras()
        {

            List<Sigeri> lista = new List<Sigeri>();
            DatabaseHelper helper = null;
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            try
            {

                helper = new DatabaseHelper(Conexion.Instancia.CadenaConexionDS());
                helper.AddParameter("@MesAño", "082019");
                dr = (DatabaseHelper)helper.ExecuteReader("PA_Control_Horas", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var obj = new Sigeri()
                    {
                        Colaborador = new Colaborador()
                        {
                            IdColaborador = dr["Id_Colaborador"].ToString(),
                            NombreColaborador = dr["Nombre_Colaborador"].ToString()
                        },
                        Proyecto = new Proyecto()
                        {
                            IdUnidadOrganizativa=dr["Id_Unidad_Organizativa"].ToString()
                        },
//Fechas son dinámicas así que no le puedo asignar un nombre de atributo ya que el nombre de las columnas van a variar a menos que cree 30 atributos a mi objeto `SIGERI`
                    };
                    lista.Add(obj);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
            finally
            {
                if (helper != null)
                    helper.Dispose();
            }
            return lista;

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre un par de alternativas, pero esta claro que antes un numero dinamico de columnas las solucion va a necesitar tambien ser dinamica, crear propiedades no es posible porque no sabes cuantas columnas tendras, salvo que definas un rango fijo de fechas y crees columnas de nombre secuencial como fecha1, ...fechaN y vayas poniendo cada fecha en estas propiedades sin hacer referencia a la fecha real

Podria usar un `DataTable`, al realizar el `Fill()` tendras un objeto que creara las columnas dinamicamente con los nombre del select

Podrias definir propieades que conoces y mapean con los campos y lo dinamico generas un `Dictionary<>`

```
public class Sigeri{
   //otras propiedades

   public Dictionary<string, decimal> Fechas {get;set;}
}
```

asi podrias usar el `Add` para agregar la fecha y su valor dinamicamente

El tema aqui va as er como conocer la `metadata` en base al reader para tomar el nombre de la columnas dinamicas

[Cómo recuperar esquema de columna mediante el método GetSchemaTable del objeto DataReader y Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/es-ar/help/310107/how-to-retrieve-column-schema-by-using-the-datareader-getschematable-m)

pero se puede usar el `GetSchemaTable()` para obtener el nombre de las columnas y poder conocer los nombres que usar como key a medida que se itera el reader

Igualmente creo que si esos datos al final se van a exportar, usa un `DataTable`

Comment: si tuvieras un ejemplo sería de mucha ayuda ya que soy nuevo en c# .net

Comment: un ejemplo de cual de todas las las opciones? si es la del datatable usa el SqlDataAdapter realizando el Fill()

Comment: como usarías el dictionary y como lo obtendrías en el controlador